Apache Guacamole (guacd) generates history files with wrong permissions
I have successfully set up a server with Guacamole, xrdp and tomcat.
I have configured the sessions to record to:
${HISTORY_PATH}/${HISTORY} which is
/var/lib/guacamole/recordings/
permissions is set to 2750:
drwxr-s--- 21 guacd tomcat 4096 Jun 24 14:26 /var/lib/guacamole/recordings/

guacd here creates a folder per session with UUID like:
# ls -l /var/lib/guacamole/recordings/
drwxr-S--- 2 guacd tomcat 4096 Jun 21 10:53 04c43a17-eb04-38bb-a48c-8f91cdb183a4
drwxr-S--- 2 guacd tomcat 4096 Jun 21 10:21 186fe24a-efda-3be2-969b-f122213bb856
drwxr-S--- 2 guacd tomcat 4096 Jun 21 10:18 1efef3b7-049e-390c-be74-effe86e1ab83

so with capital S meaning no execute permissions for the group.
also the files in the folders does not allow the tomcat group to read them:
# ls -l /var/lib/guacamole/recordings/78416a47-bd7f-3d9a-89b3-e460ab668404
total 424
-rw------- 1 guacd tomcat 430640 Jun 24 15:39 recording-172.27.0.140-172.27.0.140-frr-20240624-142610

problem is that tomcat needs readaccess to the recordings to view them in the Guacamole webinterface history.
if I manually set permissions to allow group access it works.
if I sudo to guacd and create folders and touch files, permisssions is inherited from the sgid dir correctly.
any idea what could be the cause?
